# How to combine the output of multiple commands in fish?

Tags: fish

Say I want to send the output of to commands into another.

`cat a.txt && ls`

I can do this:

`fish -c "cat a.txt && ls" | another_command`

But it seems clunky, is there a way to do this without running a new instance?

Comment: You can redirect the output with arrow symbol (greater than and less than symbols).

Comment: @Biswapriyo, right - but how to do this for two commands to pipe into `another_command`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use a [`begin...end`](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#begin) block

```
begin; cat a.txt; ls; end | another_command
```

or with whitespace

```
begin
    cat a.txt
    ls
end | another_command
```

Comment: This appears to wait until the entire block executes until anything is sent down the pipe, which renders this feature near useless.

Comment: Can I ask that your log this finding at https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues

Comment: I'm running fish 3.4.1 and it seems to output as soon as the first command outputs, at least using this test:

begin ;
                     echo hi ;
                     sleep 2 ;
                     echo bye ;
end | cat